# Streaming a large file from a GCP Bucket exceeds 1-hour max Cloud Run limit

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a large file that contains a few million rows in a GCP Bucket which I stream from a Cloud Run instance and push to a pub/sub queue.

Cloud Run has a max timeout of 1-hour which is not enough time to stream the whole file, is there an alternative option or better way of architecting/handling streaming large amounts of data from a GCP bucket?

Side thought: Does the npm package `@google-cloud/storage` have the ability to seek to a specific part of the file? Or could I increase the number of CPUs to do something such as process the file using multiple threads using a language like Go?

Comment: [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) might be useful in case the time restrictions don't work for you.

Comment: You should go for a Dataflow streaming job.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Going the route of Compute Engine was the solution we decided to take. The other solutions sounded great, but with our limitation of time, using GCE was the quickest solution we were able to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dataflow` batch job :

- `Dataflow` is a runner on `Apache Beam`. Beam is a model and open source library : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/
- `Dataflow` is fully managed on GCP and serverless
- It’s adapted for huge files and long running jobs
- `Dataflow` uses autoscaling and creates 1 or more compute engine VM on the fly to execute a job (depending on your data and performance of the job)
- Beam is proposed with Java, GO and Python sdk
- Many IO are proposed natively to interact with GCP resources (Cloud Storage, Cloud Pub Sub…)

In this case, your job is a batch job because it reads data from a bounded source (file from GCS).